# Is there any different between search engine's cached result and live results?

Tags: search-engine, bing, bing-api

I am asked by a client of mine to search within

> Bing's cached results instead of live, current results

using Bing API. I am unable to comprehend this. To me a search engine always searches within the pages that it has cached (indexed) on its servers. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He meant `bingj.com` which perhaps is used by Microsoft in the similar fashion in which Google shows cached pages.